# Default app for text files

Tags: settings

How can I make text files (e.g. myfile.txt) always open with a specific app (e.g. "Text Viewer Pro")?

I've tried Settings - Apps - Choose Default Apps, but the only choices are:
Browser app,
Digital assistent app,
Home app,
Phone app,
SMS app,
Opening links.

I've tried Settings - Apps - "Text Viewer Pro" - Set as default, however the next display:
Text Viewer Pro
Open by default ....
has no active choices (nothing selectable).

Under either scenario when I exit Settings, text files still open with a standard app (I guess it's a core app for opening text files). I can re-open each time using "Open with" scrolling down and selecting "Text Viewer Pro", but I'm trying to avoid this, as I have many text files accessible from my homescreen.

Thank you.

---

I'm using a Galaxy A10e running Android 11.
I have an icon on my homescreen "Text File 1.txt".
The actual file "Text File 1.txt" in on my Google drive.
The homescreen icon was created via the "Add to Homescreen" option of the "Drive" App.

When I tap the homescreen icon "Text File 1.txt", a core/default text file viewer opens the file.
I don't know the name of the core/default viewer. It isn't something that I have installed.

At that point, I can use the "open with" option to re-open the file using my desired app.
In my case I use "Text Viewer Pro" which has some additional viewing feaures, not available with the default/core app.

Unfortunately, when I do this, I don't get the "always" option, therefore it's always multi-step procedure
when I open such files.

Im trying to avoid the multi-step procedure, since I have many such files.

Thanks to all who respond.

Comment: Hello. What launcher app, file manager, and text editor app are you using? Which Android version and device are you using? On my Android 10 (OnePlus 6), using Nova Launcher I can create a text file shortcut (a 1x1 widget) made available by Solid Explorer File manager. First time if I open a text file under it Android asks me to select an app from a list of apps -- but also offers me to set "always". Once I press on "always" it consistently opens all text files in my QuickEdit text editor.

Comment: check the current default app settings if you can revoke defaults. installing another app sometimes revoke defaults too